# "DLL-Entrypoint 96 in oleaut32.dll was not found" error message occurs on my PowerPoint for Mac (Translated from German)

Tags: macos, powerpoint, vba7, error-messaging

For the last few days, when I open PowerPoint (Version 16.79 used on M1 MacBook Air), the error message "Microsoft Visual Basic - DLL-Entrpoint 96 in oleaut32.dll was not found" occurs every time I open a PowerPoint document. When I click away the message, it reoccurs and PowerPoint is not useable anymore. I then have to "force-close" the application.

I tried deleting the app and reinstalling the program from the App Store, that didn't work. I then deleted it and re-downloaded the entire Office-Suite from Microsoft's website, that still didn't work. Rebooting my Mac also didn't change anything.

Comment: I found out what the issue was, I disabled my add-in "Efficient-Elements", now it works fine, I just lost the add-in. I guess it wasn't compatible with the newest update, I'll probably have to wait until Efficient Elements get's an update of their own.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft fixed this yesterday (17th Nov) with update 16.79.1 but note that MAU (Microsoft Auto Update) doesn't display the .1 so you need to check the build, which is 23111614. What a chaotic week that was! Both Efficient Elements and BrightSlide will report the incompatibility if you try to use them with 16.79.0 because the call to stdole.LoadPicture is broken in the Microsoft library.